# Python BeautifulSoup Printing info from multiple tags div class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to create a python script to collect info from a website.

Trying to work out how I can extract information from 2/3 DIV tags and print.

example of html code

```
<div class="PowerDetails">
        <p class="RunningCost">$4.44</p>
        <p class="Time">peek</p>
        <p class="RunningCost"> $2.33</p>           
        <p class="Time">Off-peek</p>
</div>
```

I have managed to get it one by running a for loop, but trying to get **RunningCost** and **Time** side by side

Python Script, I'm new to it so playing around trying a few different things

```
import bs4, requests, time


while True:
    url = "https://www.website.com"
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    #soupTitle = soup.select('.RunningCost')
    soupDetail = soup.select('.Time')
    for soupDetailList in soupDetail:
       print (soupDetailList.text)
```

End goal for this script is a web monitor to list changes/updates

Comment: can you add the python code that you tried, n what is your expected result

Comment: added an example of the script. New to python so trying to self teach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` should do the job.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<html_text>" , "html.parser")

div = soup.find("div")

for r, t in zip(div.find_all("p", {"class":"RunningCost"}), 
                div.find_all("p", {"class":"Time"})):
    print(r.string, t.string)
```

---

```
$4.44 peek
 $2.33 Off-peek
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `soup` is the HTML code

```
PowerDetails = soup.find("div")
RunningCost = PowerDetails.find_all("p", _class="RunningCost")
Time = PowerDetails.find_all("p", _class="Time")
```

Comment: You can change around the variable names however you would like. RunningCost and Time are both lists.